# Hover Effect on Canva

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a radial menu, it has a canvas that creates triangles for the menu items. I need to create a hover effect when hovering, but I can't do it. Does anyone have any ideas for this?

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="radial">
            <canvas ref="canvas" class="radial-canvas"></canvas>
            <li v-for="(navItem, index) in navItems" :key="index" :class="'button-' + index" ref="navItems">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="button-inner">
                        <img src="" alt="">
                        <p>{{ navItem.label }}</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <div class="radial-inner">
                <p class="radial-inner__title" id="hovered"></p>
                <div class="radial-inner__subtitle">
                    CLICK
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                navItems: [
                    { label: 'Item 1' },
                    { label: 'Item 2' },
                    { label: 'Item 3' },
                    { label: 'Item 4' },
                    { label: 'Item 5' },
                    { label: 'Item 6' },
                    { label: 'Item 7' },
                    { label: 'Item 8' },
                ],
                radius: 305,
                spacing: 30,
                backgroundColor: '#272727',
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.positionNavItems();
            this.createCanvasBackground();
        },
        methods: {
            positionNavItems() {
                const theta = (2 * Math.PI) / this.navItems.length;
                let offset = Math.PI / 2;

                if(this.navItems.length == 2){
                    offset = Math.PI;
                }

                if(this.navItems.length == 4){
                    offset = Math.PI / 4;
                }

                if(this.navItems.length == 6){
                    offset = Math.PI / 3;
                }

                if(this.navItems.length == 8){
                    offset = Math.PI / 8;
                }

                const itemSize = this.radius + this.spacing;

                this.navItems.forEach((_, index) => {
                    const currentAngle = index * theta + offset;
                    const xPosition = (this.radius + this.spacing) * Math.cos(currentAngle);
                    const yPosition = (this.radius + this.spacing) * Math.sin(currentAngle);

                    this.$refs.navItems[index].style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${xPosition}px, ${yPosition}px)`;
                });
            },
            createCanvasBackground() {
                const canvas = this.$refs.canvas;
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                const canvasWidth = 830;
                const canvasHeight = 830;

                canvas.width = canvasWidth;
                canvas.height = canvasHeight;

                const angleStep = (2 * Math.PI) / this.navItems.length;

                for (let i = 0; i < this.navItems.length; i++) {
                    const startAngle = i * angleStep - Math.PI / 2;
                    const endAngle = (i + 1) * angleStep - Math.PI / 2;

                    const adjustedRadius = this.radius + this.spacing;

                    const radius = Math.min(canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2);

                    const spacingRadians = (this.spacing / (2 * Math.PI * adjustedRadius)) * (1 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2);
                    ctx.arc(canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2, radius, startAngle, endAngle - spacingRadians);
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
                    ctx.fill();
                }
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

I tried to create event handlers to calculate the position of the user's mouse, but when hovering, the entire canvas is highlighted, and not the individual elements that were created

Comment: Have you tried creating a collection of your radial control, each representing a different "selection state" that would be displayed based upon cursor location? So, basically, you'd have the base (no selection) RC as item 0, and then have one entry for each selectable slice with the color highlighted for the slice corresponding to a specific hover location range.

Comment: You should add vue.js tag to your question